# Mysql Data To PHP Array, then Display?

Tags: php, mysql, arrays

Alright I am still a little rusty at php/mysql. So this may not be the best method of achieving what I am trying so let me know what or how I should go about achieving this:

I am working on a small project for a storage unit list. 
In my database I have the following:

```
Unit id |  Area  |   Row   | Unit | Status         | 
        |  1-9   | 1 - 200 | 1-20 | Empty / Renter |
```

Unit Id is made of sector.section.unit

Now what I would like to do is display a list of the 20 unites from each sector and section on a page.

```
1.  1.300.1  - Empty
2.  1.300.2  - John Doe - $75 Monthly - 10x10
...
19. 1.300.19 - Jane Evens - $40 Bi-Monthly - 10x10
20. 1.300.20 - Empty
```

What I am thinking is after grabbing all mysql data that is in area 1, and in row 300 convert the data to a php assosiative array by it's unit id. Then simply do a for() statement for the 20 units of a row. Displaying the array data if any follows it. How can I go about doing this?

Or should I just go ahead and just have every single unit in the database as empty till otherwise filled?

Thank you in advanced,

Comment: Please describe better your table structure and what are you trying to do.

Comment: Sorry I tried formatting it but the filters removed it.
What I want is a vertical list counting each unit of a row (1-20)
Then display empty if nothing is in the database or the information about it if there is anything. I am thinking if there is any information connected with a storage unit. 

If there is information place it into an associative array in php and pass it back so that I can easily do an explode on the array if information is contained.

my table has:
UNIT ID | AREA | SECTION | UNIT

Comment: any chance you are looking for [this](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-assoc.php)

Comment: possibly, my only concern is will I be able to list the units prior that have no entry in the database? Some storage units are empty and do not have renters, so A list may be : unit 1: empty, unit 2: empty, unit 3: (array of information) John Doe, $75 a Month, 10x10 etc

Answer (score 0):

Here the code that works. It creates temporary tables fills it with sequence of numbers then joins that table with your units table. You will get NULLs on the rows where you don't have any record.

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE `sequence` (
  `Id` int(11) NOT NULL auto_increment,
  PRIMARY KEY  (`id`)
) ENGINE=MyISAM  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;

DELIMITER //
CREATE PROCEDURE fill_sequence()
BEGIN
  DECLARE v1 INT DEFAULT 20;
  WHILE v1 > 0 DO
INSERT sequence VALUES (NULL);
SET v1 = v1 - 1;
  END WHILE;
END //
DELIMITER ;

CALL fill_sequence();
SELECT * FROM sequence LEFT JOIN units ON (sequence.id = units.unit_id);
```